# Spark Delta merge with complex update, insert and delete operations

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I have a Delta table with the schema as shown in the example below.
Assume that the delta table 2 rows as shown in the dataframe "df1".

```
df1:
+-----+-----+----+-----+
| GUID| WFID| Uid|Value|
+-----+-----+----+-----+
|GUID1|WFID1|null|    1|
| null|WFID1|Uid1|    1|
+-----+-----+----+-----+

dfNew:
+-----+-----+----+-----+
| GUID| WFID| Uid|Value|
+-----+-----+----+-----+
|GUID1|WFID1|Uid1|    1|
| null|WFID1|Uid1|    1|
|GUID2| null|Uid2|    1|
+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

"dfNew" is the new dataframe whose data needs to be updated, deleted and inserted based on the condition:

1. When "GUID" is not null and "GUID" + "Value" match for delta table and "dfNew", then "WFID" and "Uid" should be updated with the values from "dfNew".
2. When "GUID" is null and "WFID" matches for delta table and "dfNew", then matching rows should be deleted from delta table
3. In other cases, the rows should be inserted from "dfNew" to delta table.

Expected result:

```
+-----+-----+----+-----+
| GUID| WFID| Uid|Value|
+-----+-----+----+-----+
|GUID1|WFID1|Uid1|    1|
|GUID2| null|Uid2|    1|
+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

I tried the below delta merge, but it is not working as expected. Any idea how to get the above expected result?

Below is the sample scala code:

```
:paste
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import io.delta.tables.DeltaTable

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("Test1")
      .getOrCreate();

val df1 = Seq(
    (Some("GUID1"), Some("WFID1"),  None,               1),
    (None,          Some("WFID1"),  Some("Uid1"),       1)
).toDF("GUID", "WFID", "Uid", "Value")

val deltaTablePath = "file:///D:/Test1DeltaLake"
df1.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(deltaTablePath)

val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaTablePath)
println("Original Delta table")
deltaTable.toDF.show

val dfNew = Seq(
    (Some("GUID1"), Some("WFID1"),  Some("Uid1"), 1),
    (None,          Some("WFID1"),  Some("Uid1"), 1),
    (Some("GUID2"), None,           Some("Uid2"), 1),
).toDF("GUID", "WFID", "Uid", "Value")
println("New DF for update")
dfNew.show

deltaTable.as("existing")
    .merge(dfNew.as("new"), "new.GUID = existing.GUID and new.Value = existing.Value")
    .whenMatched("existing.GUID <> null")
    .update(Map("WFID" -> col("new.WFID"),
                "Uid" -> col("new.Uid")))
    .whenMatched("existing.GUID = null and existing.WFID <> null and new.WFID = existing.WFID")
    .delete()
    .whenNotMatched
    .insertAll
    .execute()
    
println("Delta table after update")
DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaTablePath).toDF.show
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison with `NULL` should happen via `my_col IS NULL` / `my_col IS NOT NULL`.

Using `=` / `<>` to compare with `NULL` returns undefined result causing those conditions not work as expected.